# Why were the Germans drinking their own pee?

Tags: plot-explanation, as-far-as-my-feet-will-carry-me

In the movie "As Far As My Feet Will Carry Me", around the 15 minute mark, why was the German prisoner drinking his own pee? Couldn't he just lick snow or ice?

Comment: In the cold weather licking ice doesn't seems like a great suggestion.

Comment: http://thequotes.info/wp-content/uploads/dodgeball-quotes-urine-27676.jpg

Comment: I don't want to make this an answer as I've not seen the movie, but it appears based on a true story.   It might be in the film because it happened.   As far as whether it's beneficial to drink one's pee when in a desperate situation, in a hurry, no water around.  I've heard both pros and cons.  Pee won't make you sick, where still water with bacteria might but it's not good for re-hydrating the body.  Eating snow isn't good either because it takes a lot of energy to melt snow or ice.   If someone is cold, pee is warm, if somewhat gross and it won't hurt you to drink it.  (survivalist class)

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding any aesthetic considerations which they were largely below already anyway, drinking your own pee might also not be that nutritional compared to water (or frozen water for that matter). But it was one of the few possibilities they saw in getting *something* to drink. And it was warm, too, especially compared to snow.

But while they could as well have eaten snow, even if that would have been not that healthy either given their already low body temparature, there just was none really. Remember that they were still in the train. And in fact some other prisoners in that same scene were shown scratching the train walls for some ice/snow to eat. Also remember that when the train doors opened, the first thing many of the prisoners did was fall to their knees and eat the snow. So **hadn't they been trapped in the train there might have been much more prisoners eating snow**, even if pee might still be preferable at least for its temparature.